# Syntax Highlighter Evolved not working after the 3.2.1 Wordpress upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

Syntax Highlighter Evolved 3.1.3 is not working with WP 3.2.1 on my site blog.ganeshzone.net.

Is someone facing the same issue? Please suggest any workaround. All code snippets on my site are not rendering properly :(

Comment: Not experiencing any problems with my plugin (same version and same wp version). Your website seems to work fine here aswell, the code examples look as expected.

Comment: Hi I changed the theme to WP 2011 from Altahualpa after which it started working fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see whether the CSS being used leads to the correct files, and if any of CSS rules are being overridden by the new wordpress theme. You can use FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools. Also, check out [my plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) if you like.

Comment: Hi it was the theme problem only. Altahualpa and Syntax Highlighter Evolved were not working together in WP 3.2.1

Answer (score 4):

add

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

to you theme footer.php

Comment: My theme already has that, and the highlighter still doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed my Problem. Thank you +1